# What companies, projects, and researchers are using the Consumer Financial Protection Bureau (CFPB)'s API of data on consumer product complaints?

Tags: api, uses-of-open-data

This data is available for bulk download and via an API at http://www.consumerfinance.gov/complaintdatabase/.

Answer (score 1):

Our team at Beyond the Arc makes extensive use of the CFPB database.  You can see our latest analyses on [our blog](http://beyondthearc.com/blog).

Comment: Thank you. It would be great if you could summarize the content in the answer itself.